# AngularJS filter ng-repeat based on value from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display all data (contacts) that have *bookmarked* value set to 1

To do that I used this peace of code:

```
<ul class="span5">
        <li class="nav-pills nav-stacked contact-row" data-ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy:'firstName'" ng-show="contact.bookmarked('0')">
            <span id=" ct-details-{{contact.id}}" data-ng-click="displayContact(contact.id)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="contact-data details-hidden" href="">
                <span class="span3 contact-name">
                    {{contact.firstname + ' ' + contact.lastname}}
                </span>
            </span>
            <button class="btn editContact" id="deleteContact-{{contact.id}}" data-ng-click="deleteContact(contact.id)">Delete</button>
            <button class="btn editContact" id="editContact-{{contact.id}}" data-ng-click="editContact(contact.id)">Edit</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

When I use this code, contacts are not displayed (ones with value 1 and ones with value 0 are not displayed). Does someone knows where's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: `contact.bookmarked('0')` are you sure this returns what you expect? It should probably be `contact.bookmarked == 1`, or use a filter as it says in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a filter on your `ngRepeat` query.

```
 data-ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:{bookmarked:'0'} | orderBy:'firstName'"
```

Read more about here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your example but it's not working... Data are not showed even if bookmarked equals to 0 or 1

Comment: Perhaps you want to remove the `ng-show="contact.bookmarked('0')"` part which isn't needed anymore (without questioning if it was working before obviously).

Comment: Thank you Ropstah. It was error in my controller. It was not your fault, you code is working. Thank you for help